# How to compute inverse of this matrix

Tags: matrices, riemannian-geometry, inverse

If $g=(g_{ij})$ where
$$
g_{ij}=\delta_{ij}+\frac{x^ix^j}{T^2},\quad T^2=K^2-\sum_{i=1}^n(x^i)^2
$$
I want to show its inverse matrix $g^{ij}=\delta^{ij}-\frac{x^ix^j}{K^2}$. But I don't know how to start, could anyone give me some help?

Comment: Have you computed $\sum_k g^{ik}g_{kj}$?

Comment: Note that $g = I + {1 \over T^2} x x^T$ and $g^{-1} = I - {1 \over K^2} x x^T$. Multiple and simplify.

Comment: @copper.hat very thanks! that's what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Sherman-Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) says that whenever $A$ is an invertible square matrix of size $n$ and $u,v\in \Bbb R^n$ are column vectors such that $1+v^\top A^{-1}u\neq 0$, then $A+uv^\top$ is invertible with inverse $$(A+uv^\top)^{-1} = A^{-1} - \frac{A^{-1}uv^\top A^{-1}}{1+v^\top A^{-1}u}.$$In your case, the matrix $G = (g_{ij})_{i,j=1}^n$ equals ${\rm Id}_n + (x/T)(x/T)^\top$, so $$1 + (x/T)^\top(x/T) = 1+\frac{K^2-T^2}{T^2} = (K/T)^2$$implies that $$G^{-1}=  {\rm Id}_n - \frac{(x/T)(x/T)^2}{(K/T)^2} = {\rm Id}_n - (x/K)(x/K)^\top,$$as required.